# Como mostrar una alerta en python?

Tags: python

Quiero validar un rango de fecha y si esta mal, mostrarle una alerta al usuario, pero no se como hacerlo, estoy trabajando en el **filter.py** lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
        if fecha2 <= fecha1:
            print "fecha incorrecta"

        if fecha1 != "None" and fecha2 != "None":
            fecha1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha1, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d %b %Y")
            fecha1 = fecha1.upper()
            fecha2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha2, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d %b %Y")
            fecha2 = fecha2.upper()
            TopDescarga.objects.all().delete()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO comportamiento_topdescarga(imsi_pref_top,operador_top,descarga_top) select imsi_pref,nomb_oper,round(avg(descarga)::numeric,3) from comportamiento_trafico_de_datos WHERE fecha BETWEEN '%"+ fecha1 +"%' AND '%"+ fecha2 +"%' group by nomb_oper,imsi_pref order by avg(descarga) desc ")


        elif fecha1 != "None":
            fecha1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha1, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d %b %Y")
            fecha1 = fecha1.upper()

            TopDescarga.objects.all().delete()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO comportamiento_topdescarga(imsi_pref_top,operador_top,descarga_top) select imsi_pref,nomb_oper,round(avg(descarga)::numeric,3) from comportamiento_trafico_de_datos WHERE fecha like '%"+ fecha1 +"%' group by nomb_oper,imsi_pref order by avg(descarga) desc")
```

Comment: Eso es para web o escritorio? Sería bueno si pudieras dar un poco más de contexto.

Comment: es para web !!!

Comment: estas usando django o algún framework? Tanto para el lado del servidor, como para el cliente.

Comment: Hola @Coloma, creo que el código que pones no está relacionado con la pregunta. O en todo caso, las primeras dos líneas ya muestran la alerta que quieres. Asegúrate que lo que quieres hacer corresponde al _backend_ de tu aplicación.

Comment: Estoy usando Django, y esa alerta que estoy mostrando mela imprime en la consola, NO en la pantalla....